# How can I evaluate whether overfitting is problematic in regression when one variable is categorical with one level having few cases?

Tags: regression, overfitting

I am doing a linear regression of the price of cars based on various characteristics of the cars including "type" (sport, truck, etc). In the data set that I have, there are 3 hybrid cars.

How should I evaluate whether including those cars causes a problem with overfitting?  I ran the model with and without that group and R^2 was not much changed, but the parameter estimates did change.

Answer (score 2):

Overfitting can definitely be an issue but in my mind it is easier to think of this as an estimation problem.  For the non-hybrids it seems you have a large enough sample size to estimate $Y$.  The sample size would then also be large enough to estimate the average $Y$ marginalizing over all car types.  For the particular estimate of $Y$ given that car type is hybrid, the confidence interval for the unknown population mean will be very wide and the estimate is probably unreliable.  It remains to be seen whether including the hybrids helps or hurts the overall model.  It is possible that they give you a better estimate of $\sigma$ and are worth having.